# Sort divs by data-event-date in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have looked at the other posts relating to this but either I couldn't figure out how to implement their solution or it looked really messy.

Basically I have a load of divs with the `data-event-date` tag and a date rendered in the `d/m/Y` format and I need them putting in date ascending using JavaScript.

Here is the page with a list of divs
https://sheffieldskillsacademy.com/locations/sheffield/jobs

```
<script>
(function($){
    var container = $(".sort-list");
    var items = $(".sort-item");

    items.each(function() {
       // Convert the string in 'data-event-date' attribute to a more
       // standardized date format
       var BCDate = $(this).attr("data-event-date").split("/");
       var standardDate = BCDate[1]+" "+BCDate[0]+" "+BCDate[2];
       standardDate = new Date(standardDate).getTime();
       $(this).attr("data-event-date", standardDate);

    });


    items.sort(function(a,b){
        a = parseFloat($(a).attr("data-event-date"));
        b = parseFloat($(b).attr("data-event-date"));
        return a>b ? -1 : a<b ? 1 : 0;
    }).each(function(){
        container.prepend(this);
    });

});
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Post the code you already tried.

Comment: U can also use sever side or sql query to sort it according date. date

Comment: @freeek posted it above

Comment: @AnkurMishra part of the data is called from a job site API so Its not stored in our database.

Comment: Should be passing the values to `new Date` as individual arguments. The space delimited string is not a proper ISO format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should be using `new Date(year, monthIndex, day)` format to create the dates. The space delimited string is a non standard ISO date format.

Then in the sort function you can take advantage of the `-` operator casting strings to numbers automatically

```js
var container = $(".sort-list");
var items = $(".sort-item");

items.attr('data-event-date', function(i, currVal) {
  const dParts = currVal.split('/');
  const date = new Date(dParts[2], dParts[1] - 1, dParts[0]);
                             // ^^^ individal arguments
  return date.getTime();
});

$('button').click(function() {
  items.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).data('event-date') - $(b).data('event-date');
  });
  container.html(items);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sort-list">
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="27/09/2019">27/09/2019</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="31/12/2020">31/12/2020</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="01/01/2016">01/01/2016</li>
</ul>

<button>Sort ascending</button>
```

Comment: how would I make it so on page load it puts them in ascending order rather than having to click a button?

Comment: Just unwrap the click listener surrounding the sort